# Wrong value of pixels color when reading from a mat

Tags: java, opencv, pixel

Im having some problems lately about getting the color of a pixel using Open CV and java . This is what i did.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat a = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\OpenCv\\color.png",Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPixelColor(0, 0, a))); //top left
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPixelColor(9, 0, a))); //top right
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPixelColor(0, 9, a))); // bottom left 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPixelColor(9, 9, a))); // bottom right
```

So this code returns the following

```
[255.0, 255.0, 0.0] //top left
[0.0, 0.0, 255.0] //top right
[255.0, 0.0, 0.0] // bottom left 
[0.0, 255.0, 255.0]// bottom right
```

for this image [image] which is a  10*10 image.

This is the right values from photoshop for each color.

```
[0, 255.0, 255.0] Cyan //top left
[0.0, 0.0, 255.0] Blue //top right
[255.0, 0.0, 0.0] Red // bottom left 
[255.0, 255.0, 0] Yellow // bottom right
```

The image loads up as mat from type CV_8UC3 so its rbg.

Anyone knows why is this happening ? 
Also if im using cvtColor to change from bgr -> rbg im not getting the right output still

```
[0.0, 255.0, 255.0] Cyan ok //top left
[255.0, 0.0, 0.0] Should be blue  , is red //top right
[0.0, 0.0, 255.0] Should be red , is blue // bottom left
[255.0, 255.0, 0.0] Yellow ok // bottom right
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, OpenCV tends to use BGR instead of RGB if the ordering is not specified. It is accurate to use `cvtColor` to change it from BGR to RGB.

Second, the`getPixelColor` call parameters are not `(x, y)`, but `(row, column)`, which is equivalent to `(y, x)`. This means what appears to be the top right is actually the bottom left, and vice versa.

Comment: Oh wow , thats it , didnt knew that its the opposite way , thanks!